# how I can access menu items in fragment?

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments

I was created menu items in main activity now I have fragment and I wanna access menu items ( like copy , paste,share ) in fragment .

```
public class Frag_Angel extends Fragment {
.....

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    setRetainInstance(true);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_angel, wrapper, true);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
.....
}
```

I wrote below code but does't work for me !

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.copy:{
        refreshList();       // Add a measurement

    }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void refreshList() {
    // TODO
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refreshing the first list...",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and I can't use getSystemService !

Comment: i know it's a long time ago, but what resolved your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Override onOptionsItemSelected.